# How to look-up dates and find closest match

Tags: sql, lookup, amazon-athena

I have this problem using SQL where I want to find the closest matched date between two columns. Imagine this is my data-set:

[image]

'LY Date' is just last years date of 'Date' column I want to put into the new column 'Closest Date' which 'Date' that the 'LY Date', for each row, is closest to.

Example: the 22-02-2022 has last years date of 21-02-2021. This date is closest to the 15-02-2021 from 'Date' column so I put it in 'Closest Date'

Answer (score 0):

I’ve referred to the columns as ‘DATE.DATE’ and ‘LYDATE.DATE’.

You can start from the LYDATE and obtain the top 1 record from DATE when DATE is sorted descending and only contains items less than ‘LYDATE’. You can then flip the DATE table and obtain the top 1 after filtering out those items less than LYDATE. This will give you the closest date that’s less than what we are looking for and the closest date that’s greater than what we are looking for.

I then calculate the date difference between those two limits to see which has smaller difference, and return the appropriate limit value as ClosestDate.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(ns,lowerlimit.date, LYDate.date) < DATEDIFF(ns, upperlimit.date, LYDATE.date) THEN lowerlimit.date ELSE upperlimit.date END as ClosestDate
    FROM LYDate
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 DATE FROM DATE WHERE DATE.DATE < LYDATE.DATE ORDER BY DATE.DATE DESC) lowerlimit
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 DATE FROM DATE WHERE DATE.DATE > LYDATE.DATE ORDER BY DATE.DATE ASC) upperlimit
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've just added a tag - I'm using AWS Athena for my queries and it doesn't support functions like OUTER APPLY.

Comment: I am not familiar with Amazon Athena. I decided to leave my answer incase someone using MS SQL came across this question.